# Running vim-lldb on Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, vim

I am trying to run the vim debugger plugin "[vim-lldb](https://github.com/gilligan/vim-lldb)" on MacOS Mojave with vim 8.1.  The plugin documentation notes that vim "`python`" support is required.  I confirmed using `vim --version` that while my build has `+python3` support, it reports "`-python`".

Reviewing the [homebrew commits](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/1a5a30703721b24198ef165059756ba35813511e#diff-846301f7dd387adfc50930cbbe0d9fca), it appears that support for python2 has been removed from brew's vim.  When you try to use the associated install options "`with-python@2`" and "`with-python`", brew now reports the warning:

```
Warning: vim: this formula has no --with-python(@2) option so it will be ignored!
```

Are there any options to get vim-lldb working using brew? More generally, are there any options to get python2 support on a Mac or to have a python2 complaint vim plugin run on python3?

Comment: You can't install plugin without python support?

Comment: Not that I can tell.  The docs say under requirements: `a python-enabled vim (check with ":python print 2")`.  When I tried the plugin in a VM with `python` support, the plug-in just worked.

Answer (score 1):

The `lldb` python module can only be imported into environments that have a matching python version to what LLDB was compiled against. In other words, if you are running `vim-lldb`, you need vim's python (the version vim was built with) to match the python version LLDB was compiled with.

You can verify `lldb`'s python:

```sh
# make sure you have lldb
$> which lldb
# /usr/bin/lldb
$> lldb -P
# /some/path/to/pythonX
```

Verify the version LLDB points to matches the version vim uses.

```sh
vim --version | grep python
```

You may need to recompile either LLDB or vim to get their python versions matching.

I have a Python 3 compatible version available at https://github.com/67hz/vim-lldb
There are instructions in the README for setting a custom path to LLDB in your `.vimrc`. I have several LLDB's compiled against different python's in my setup, so I find it's easiest to point to the lldb path straight from `.vimrc`. It makes switching a whole lot easier as well as keeping track of which lldb vim is actually pointing to.